# Java GUI Freezes

Tags: java, user-interface, freeze

I am trying to create a Simple TCP Client Server Application Interface
where user can start or stop the server when they pres the respective buttons
I have created a StartServer Button when user presses the button it should connected to the server
the problem am facing is when the user clicks the button noting happens and the interface halts

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultListModel dlm=new DefaultListModel();
    String clientSentence; 
    String capitalizedSentence;
    try {
        welcomeSocket= new ServerSocket(6789);
        dlm.addElement("server started..");            
        dlm.addElement("Server Waiting for Connections on Port 6789");
        jList1.setModel(dlm); 
        displayfull();
         while(true)
        {                
        DataOutputStream outToClient = null;
        try {


            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            //dlm.addElement("Client Connected ");
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            //dlm.addElement("Obtained a handle on Client Input Stream");
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            //dlm.addElement("Obtained a handle on Client Output Stream");
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            //dlm.addElement("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            //dlm.addElement("Message Sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } 

    }               

    } catch (Exception e) {
        dlm.addElement(e);
    }
   jList1.setModel(dlm); 
    displayfull();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have an infinite `while` loop, the method is never returning and hence the interface is forever waiting.

Comment: You're blocking the event dispatching thread

Comment: Is there any other way to implement it.I have tried it by create a separate thread but still the same problem for the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have hinted at, you are spending precious time on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
If you read through the tutorial on how to do [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) you will discover you are given tools like the [Swing worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

There are many questions like this on Stack Overflow, some more helpful than others.

- [Java's Swing Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564388/javas-swing-threading)
- [JFrame without Freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423980/execute-process-in-java-without-jframe-freezing)
- [Freezing on Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164311/application-is-freezing-when-database-is-called)